# nls poor curve fitting

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I'm having trouble fitting several different sigmoidal curves. 
A little help for a better fitting would be really appreciated.

I am trying three different models:

**4 parameters**

```
 nls(y ~ a + (k-a) /(1 + (x/c)^e)^m, start=list(a=a_start, k=k_start, c=c_start, m=m_start, e=e_start), control = list(maxiter = 50000, minFactor=1/2000, warnOnly=T), algorithm = "port")
```

**5 parameters**

```
nls(y ~ a + (k-a) /(1 + exp(-1/c*(x-e)))^m, start=list(a=a_start, k=k_start, c=c_start, m=m_start, e=e_start), trace=T, lower=c(a=-10000, k=0, c=0, m=0, e=0), upper=c(a=1000, k=100000, c=50, m=5, e=50), control = list(maxiter = 50000, minFactor=1/2000, warnOnly=T))
```

**5 parameters with weights**

```
nls(y ~ a + (k-a) /(1 + exp(-1/c*(x-e)))^m, weights = (1/residuals(fit)^2), start=list(a=a_start, k=k_start, c=c_start, m=m_start, e=e_start), trace=T, lower=c(a=-10000, k=0, c=0, m=0, e=0), upper=c(a=1000, k=100000, c=50, m=5, e=50), control = list(maxiter = 50000, minFactor=1/2000, warnOnly=T))
```

4pl good fitting
[image]

5pl good fitting
[image]

poor fitting
[image]

sigmoid function
[image]

Comment: I don't see how you can infer from these data points that they can be described by a sigmoidal curve. You don't have data from the upper part of the sigmoid.

Comment: Sorry, I zoom in an interval to show the poor fitting. Now I added at the bottom a complete data points example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have partially resolved my problem.
Since I was interested in a good fitting at the beginning of the growth, I have used custom weights in order to give more importance in that region.